# Generic OAuth Library C#

Tags: c#, api, twitter, linkedin-api, foursquare

**What i am Trying to do:**

Write a `Generic Library in C#` to handle OAuth Flow to every service ( Just like Twitter,LinkedIn and Foursquare). The hardest part is that, i want to `simulate all the user input in code` so that no user action is needed to click on buttons like "Ok,I will Allow It",or even writing its username/password.

**Doubts That i have so far:**

1 - Whats the usage of the `authenticity_token` in twitters API ?

2 - What are the factors that all services use, so that i can implement a generic usage of OAuth Flow. For example i´ve found the first Step is really easy to make a Generic method to execute. All i have to do is change the URL for the webRequest,and BAM, i have the Request tokens.

3 - How do i Get the Verifier for each service? In `LinkedIn Service` for instance, i was able to parse a page to fetch this value, but i can't find this `verifier` for twitter API for example. Even when authorizing in browser my aplication, i see no `Verifier` in any HTML during the flow, or any JavaScript generating it.

**Observations:**

1 - I know that there are Lots of OAuth Libraries out there, like [this](http://oauth.net/code/) or [that](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/oauth.aspx) ones, but there is no Library that allows me to make what i want to, that is to Authenticate and authorize a user, without prompting for any user input.

2 - I can't,by any means,ask for user input. All the values like username and password for the authentication, will be hardcoded and every user will use the same account for this requests.

3 - I also know, that there are other posts here that i've written, with almost the same doubts, and the reason i am resposting is to try to make it clearer and fresher.

4 - Sorry about any english mistake or missunderstanding of concepts in advance.

**Basic Code Sample:**

This is, for instance, the method i am using (that is avaible widely abroad the web) for getting request tokens for any service. All i have to do is change the `REQUEST_TOKEN` value to the specific url to be used for a service,so i can get the Tokens for LinkedIn,Twitter or Foursquare for instance. But i can't manage to apply the same process in the other steps.

```
public string AuthorizationLinkGet()
    {
        string ret = null;

        string response = oAuthWebRequest(Method.GET, REQUEST_TOKEN, String.Empty);
        if (response.Length > 0)
        {
            //response contains token and token secret.  We only need the token.
            NameValueCollection qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(response);

            if (qs["oauth_callback_confirmed"] != null)
            {
                if (qs["oauth_callback_confirmed"] != "true")
                {
                    throw new Exception("OAuth callback not confirmed.");
                }
            }

            if (qs["oauth_token"] != null)
            {
                ret = AUTHORIZE + "?oauth_token=" + qs["oauth_token"];
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Don't**.

OAuth was designed to require a user to press that button once. If you automate it you will have your application key revoked and your program will no longer work.

What you need to do is save locally the authorization token and reuse that. The user clicks"I Allow" once then you re-use the authorization token for future connections. You need to check to make sure it is not expired, and if it is you just re-authorize and they click "I Allow" again.

No website doing OAuth correctly will allow you to bypass the website authorization, some will allow you to pass the username and password via a query and get a token, but if they have a web authorization, you MUST have the user manually do it.

If you are the OAuth provider and consumer you need to do something Dropbox did for their v0 of the API (I can't find any links to their old API, if anyone can find it edit this post) that passed the username and password to a special address that returned a autorization token without using a webpage. Or you need to use a different authentication scheme than OAuth.

Comment: Are you sure ? 
So, there is no need, by any means, i can do it mannualy ? Because, i just finished last month with linkedin, connecting a user (username,password) without prompting for any user input. `Does this makes me a hacker ?` Just kidding, so you are saying that i can't do this for every service ?

Comment: I am not the Provider, i will be the consumer, using the API of the services.

Comment: There is a reason the OAuth SDK itseld does not allow you to do this, because your not suppose to do it, the user is suppose to approve it.  In theory you should only have to do it once.

Comment: It may not make you a hacker, but **if they do not provide a API to authenticate without using a webpage and you bypass it** your app will violate the agreement you agreed to when they gave you your application key. And violating the agreement means your application key will be pulled, and if it is pulled none of your users can use your app. You need to authorize once and save the token. If you can not authorize on the device it is supposed to run on you will need to authorize on something else and then have some way to transmit the token to the device that it will use later.

Comment: Note that the LinkedIn Terms of Use do not allow for Open API applications to collect username and password rather than using OAuth.  If your application comes to the notice of our legal team you'll likely get shut down.